# matplotlib: plot hist2d piecewise

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a large sample  stored in the arrays `a` and `b` with matplotlib's `hist2d` feature. However, generating `H, xedges, yedges, img` does not work directly for this data, as it uses too much memory. It works for half the number of samples, though, so I would like to do something like

```
H_1, xedges_1, yedges_1, img_1 = plt.hist2d(a[:len(a)/2], b[:len(b)/2], bins = 10)
```

followed by

```
H_2, xedges_2, yedges_2, img_2 = plt.hist2d(a[len(a)/2:], b[len(b)/2:], bins = 10)
```

While perhaps deleting the first half of the arrays after calculating the first set of variables. Is there a way to merge these two sets of variables and generate a combined plot for the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (and only if!) you specify the bin edges manually, then your histograms will be compatible. You can simply add the occurences of each bin for both subsets, and you'll recover the full histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.random.rand(200)*10
b=np.random.rand(200)*10
binmin=min(a.min(),b.min())
binmax=max(a.max(),b.max())
H_1, xedges_1, yedges_1, img_1 = plt.hist2d(a[:len(a)/2], b[:len(b)/2], bins = np.linspace(binmin,binmax,10+1))
H_2, xedges_2, yedges_2, img_2 = plt.hist2d(a[len(a)/2:], b[len(b)/2:], bins = np.linspace(binmin,binmax,10+1))
H_3, xedges_3, yedges_3, img_3 = plt.hist2d(a, b, bins = np.linspace(binmin,binmax,10+1))
```

Result:

```
In [150]: (H_1+H_2==H_3).all()
Out[150]: True
```

Which you can easily plot using `plt.pcolor`. That's what `hist2d` seems to use, albeit with an additional transpose of the data:

```
plt.figure()
plt.pcolor((H_1+H_2).T)
```

`img_3` (left) vs `(H_1+H_2).T` (right):

[image: from H_3] [image: from (H_1+H_2).T]

Comment: Thanks. However, in my case, `a` is simply an a sorted array of integers and I would like to explicitly specify the number of bins (not bin edges) on the x and y axes. Is it still possible to use your method?

Comment: You can define whatever you like, the point is to use the same definition for both subsets. For `nbin` bins, you can just use `np.linspace(binmin,binmax,nbin+1)`, which will create `nbin+1` edges uniformly between `binmin` and `binmax` (you might have to change the two borders a bit to make sure every point is included in the histograms). If your question is related to having *separate* bins in the two dimensions: you can use `bins=[np.linspace(a.min(),a.max(),nbin_a+1), np.linspace(b.min(),b.max(),nbin_b+1)]`.